# Part of a dynamic page invisible depending on item on the page

Tags: php, html

Sorry about the strange title, I honestly tried to make it more precise but I couldn't, as it's such a strange problem. I have a page on a website I'm creating, and this page is like a profile page for a book. Now, the strange thing:

for some books, the page loads properly and for some nothing except the first big `<div>` is visible - but when I look at the source code, it's exactly the same for both pages (except for different titles, book description etc). You can see a visible and invisible page through the links below, and you will see what I mean. I am completely stumped by this, as the page source shows all the same content and on one page it's fine but on the other it's like everything has `display:hidden;`.

Working page:

http://jovansfreelance.com/booklist/list/item/Game-Of-Thrones-Book-1

Broken page:

http://jovansfreelance.com/booklist/list/item/A

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Explanation of book title being just 'A': the title is typed in by the user, and the actual title is fetched from Amazon. So if a user types in 'A' the first result is 'A Christmas Carol' so that gets displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is within `'div.item_super_wiki'` block: in the first page you've quoted it's a correct markup, but in the second it's...

```
<DIV>This engrossing tale relates...
```

And that big DIV is not closed properly. Therefore HTML parser tries to reconstruct a correct markup by itself - and fails a bit. With markup broken all these footer elements (`'div#page'` etc.) become part of `'div.item_super_info` block, which has `overflow:hidden` as part of its styling. Hence the disappearance. )